# Delphi Open Tools - How to Use IOTABuildEventProvider and IOTABuildEvent?

Tags: delphi, opentools

I'm developing a project group manager now that DDEVExtensions is no longer supported, I've got a handle on the version info and other project attributes - however I want to access the build events as well.

I've found the two interfaces to use, IOTABuildEventProvider and IOTABuildEvent, but can find no examples, documentation at all anywhere.

Just want to find out how to create a IOTABuildEventProvider from the IOTAProject interface instance I have, and how to use it.

Thanks

Comment: Call `Supports(AProject, IOTABuildEventProvider, AProvider)` where `AProject` is your `IOTAProject` and `AProvider` is the returned`IOTABuildEventProvider` reference. I'm just using it to check if `HasBuildEvents` returns `True`

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but I had to find another work around - which was to create an external build script and set and forget a single build event on all projects.